# User Object is not Showing in Master Detail Relationship

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have a custom object: One field I want to make as master-detail with User object such that when user is deleted .Object is also deleted, but when I try to make the master-detail relationship it is not showing the User Object. Can any one please tell me why this is, and how to resolve it??

Answer (score 1):

```
 you cannot create a master-detail relationship in which the User or Lead objects are the master.
```

check it here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm

Also, you can't delete a user record.